# How to find position and rotation intervals for spawning objects in allowable alignments?

Tags: unity, 3d, rotation

I'm trying to find intervals of positions and rotations to spawn the cup in front of the hand so that it is graspable (The cup is child of the hand).

[image: Mug and hand model]

The problem is that I'm moving the mug in the editor in order to find good rotations and coordinates, but sometimes if I move the object along a direction, the other coordinates (or angles if I rotate) also change.
Is there an easier way to find ranges of points and rotations in this case?

Comment: For [why multiple Euler angles can change when you rotate on just one axis, see this Q&A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/136174/39518). I like to say [Euler angles are a fiction](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/165510/39518) for ease of data entry, not an accurate intuitive model of the underlying reality of 3D rotation. [For expressing angular limits, it often helps to choose a base orientation at the center of your range and deviations relative to that, or use vectors](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/162298/39518).

Comment: I would suggest starting your research on the IK, inverse-kinematics, solvers.  Similar mathematics approaches would be applicable to this problem. If you do not need dynamic runtime solutions, baking the brute force solutions at specified distances and rotations and lerping/slerping at runtime may work.